# Zip an order before download on Github

Tags: github, download, zip

How can I download only a folder or directory and do a compression before from a remote Git repo hosted on GitHub?
The problem is the folder has some executables *.exe in  it, and I have to zip (protect) it before going through the firewall.

Comment: There is an API for the entire branch https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents#download-a-repository-archive-zip but no way to pick only a specific directory, your best bet is another server to zip the files for you.

Comment: this is the first question on stackoverflow, and I got a -1 why?

Answer (score 0):

You can associate to that repository (assuming you are the owner, if not, fork it) a GitHub Action.

That GitHub Action can do a [sparse checkout](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/sparse-checkout-action) of just the folder you want.

The same GitHub action workflow script can [then compress the folder](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/easy-zip-files) and [upload it as an artifact](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact).

A `curl` call can then [download that zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65650260/6309).